# Where should the "mobile" tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the main site, there's a "mobile" tag however I'm not sure how and where to use it. Should I only use it if I have problems with mobile games or should I use it for every mobile game?

**Description**

> This tag is to refer to questions about games and associated content
>   on mobile platforms such as Android, iOS, and Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag when the issue is with the mobile version of the game, if there's multiple versions.

For example, if you had a problem with candy crush soda on mobile, but it was fine online via facebook for example, you could use the mobile tag to show this (you should also specify this in the question also).

Don't just tag something with [mobile] simply because it has a mobile version, you wouldn't tag everything [PS4] if it's a PC game and had a PS4 port after all.

Comment: If the game only has a mobile version, for example Clash Royale and Miitomo, should I add the "mobile" tag then?

Comment: @nelson2tm no, do not do that. Tags are supposed to help categorize questions. If the existing tags are for a mobile only game, adding the mobile tag doesn't categorize it further.

Comment: No. If there's only a mobile version, there's no need to specify that it's on mobile.

Comment: You can also use [mobile] as a placeholder if the mobile game you wish to ask about doesn't have a tag yet and you don't meet the required rep to make one. (then leave a comment for someone to make the tag) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the mobile tag should just be deleted.  It's a generic platform tag, and we should be using [android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) or [ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) in it's place, if questions are specific to those versions.  It's only used in five questions, and all of them are using it with a game tag.  Those should be reviewed, and replaced with the more specific tag, if applicable.